# Error: The method 'getPositionStream' isn't defined for the class 'Geolocator'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, geolocation, dart-pub

Using flutter I try to retrieve the current position using StreamSubscription and getPositionStream in geo locator.
But I keep getting the error: Error: The method 'getPostionStream' isn't defined for the class 'Geolocator'.

Here is my function:

```
void getLocationUpdates(){
StreamSubscription<Position> homeTabPostionStream;

homeTabPostionStream = geoLocator.getPositionStream(locationOptions).listen((Position position){
  currentPosition = position;
});
```

Here I created the variables:

```
var geoLocator = Geolocator();
var locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation, distanceFilter: 4);
```

As you requested I write the entire code for reference.

Here is the entire code:

```
class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeTabState createState() => _HomeTabState();
}

class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {

  GoogleMapController mapController;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  Position currentPosition;

  DatabaseReference tripRequestRef;

  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
  var locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation, distanceFilter: 4);


  void getCurrentPosition() async{

    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);
    currentPosition = position;
    LatLng pos = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(pos));

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 135),
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: googlePlex,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
            _controller.complete(controller);
            mapController = controller;

            getCurrentPosition();
          },
        ),
        Container(
          height: 135,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: BrandColors.colorPrimary,
        ),

        Positioned(
          top: 60,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              AvailabilityButton(
                title: 'GO ONLINE',
                color: BrandColors.colorOrange,
                onPressed: (){

                  GoOnline();

                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );
  }

  void GoOnline(){
    Geofire.initialize('driversAvailable');
    Geofire.setLocation(currentFirebaseUser.uid, currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude);

    tripRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('drivers/${currentFirebaseUser.uid}/newtrip');
    tripRequestRef.set('waiting');
    
    tripRequestRef.onValue.listen((event) {



    });

  }

  void getLocationUpdates(){
    StreamSubscription<Position> homeTabPostionStream;

    homeTabPostionStream = geoLocator.getPositionStream(locationOptions).listen((Position position){
      currentPosition = position;
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to instantiate `Geolocator`. `getPositionStream()` is a static method called like so, `Geolocator.getPositionStream()`. The args passed to the method are all optional params as well. No locationOptions necessary.

Updated

```
void getLocationUpdates(){
  StreamSubscription<Position> homeTabPostionStream;

  homeTabPostionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation,
    distanceFilter: 4).listen((event) {
       ...
    });
}
```

You can remove

```
var geoLocator = Geolocator();
var locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation, distanceFilter: 4);
```

Comment: I am on the last version

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thx for help :)

Comment: I downgraded, so in my pubspec.yaml has now 
geolocator: 5.3.2+2
It would be nice to have backward compability, even in freeware.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a missing letter (i) on your method: getPostionStream. It has to be like:

```
void getLocationUpdates(){
  StreamSubscription<Position> homeTabPostionStream;

  homeTabPostionStream = geoLocator.getPositionStream().listen((Position position){
  currentPosition = position;
});
```

Comment: Yeah, sure my mistake, but this dosen't solved the problem, I have same error.

Comment: Ok, then can you share the total of the page?

Comment: Where are you calling the getLocationUpdates() method?

Comment: I will call in GO ONLINE button, it's not implemented yet because I got stuck on this.